# Ошибка с константной

Tags: c++, stl

У меня есть структура, которая хранит событие и флаг является оно последним или нет

```
struct Event{
   string event;
   bool ch;
};
```

Также есть класс, как некоторое хранилище

```
class Data{
public:
    void Add(const int& a, Event& ev);
    void Last(const int& a);
private:
    map<int,set<Event>> m;
};
```

И функция добавления элемента с флагом, является он последним или нет

```
void Data::Add( const int& a,Event& ev){
    if(m.count(a) > 0){
        m[a].insert(ev);
        for(auto& val:m[a]){   
            val.ch=false;
        }
    ev.ch=true;
    }else{
        m[a].insert(ev);
        ev.ch=true;
    }
}
```

Почему выдает ошибку при изменение параметра `ch` в цикле `for(auto& val:m[a])` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Потому что `map` и `set` хранят свои элементы в отсортированном порядке, так что их нельзя менять произвольно (ключ в `map`, элементы в `set`) - иначе нарушится порядок, а потому они константны. Вы же пытаетесь изменить `Event` в `set` - вот компилятор и справедливо возмущен...

Можно выкрутиться, если у вас и правда `ch` не принимает участия в сравнении и не могут быть два одинаковых события, но с разным `ch` (словом, сравнение идет только по полю `event`), объяснив это компилятору:

```
struct Event{
    string event;
    mutable bool ch;
    bool operator < (const Event& e) const { return event < e.event; }
};
```

Comment: а насколько большая разница с моей перегрузкой?
 `bool operator<( const Event& lhs,const Event& rhs){return lhs.event<rhs.event;
}`

Comment: Тогда просто допишите `mutable` к полю `ch`...